# Add cronjob with bash script - No crontab for root

Tags: linux, debian, bash, cron, shell

I have a deployment script and in it I'm trying to add a cron job. This is the code I am using which I found on stackoverflow. I'm running debian 8.

```
# ADD CRON
crontab -l > mycron
echo "10 * * * * cd /var/www/test/ && ./test" >> mycron
crontab mycron
rm mycron
```

When I run these commands I get the reply: `no crontab for root`

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I get it so I can add this cron job using a bash script? Thank you.

Comment: Check if you have `root` in `/etc/cron.deny`.

Comment: @ott-- I don't have that file at all, just ```cron.d                                              cron.daily                                  
cron.hourly                       
cron.monthly            
crontab                                          
cron.weekly```

Comment: Hate to ask a dumb question, but are you root when you execute these commands?  Also instead of the raw commands please provide the transcript of their run.

Comment: @mdpc I am root yes. I will upload the full script when I get to my laptop but it's just that command with a ```#!/bin/bash``` header

Comment: @JennyD my reply in the answer below solved it which doesn't appear on you link

Comment: Typically when scripting and packaging (and running as root) dropping a new file with a cron entry in `/etc/cron.d` is easier to maintain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like (a) root's crontab is initially empty and (b) the `-e` option is set in the shell.

If the user's crontab file is empty then `crontab -l` exits with status 1.

If shell is running with `-e` option then it will exit immediately on failure (defined as exiting with non-zero status).

Look for `errexit` in the output of `echo $SHELLOPTS` to check for this setting. Turn it off in the current shell with `set +e`.

Comment: The problem was there was no file automatically created in /var/spool/crontab/root so I made a blank one in my script and then the code above worked fine.

Comment: echo $SHELLOPTS -> braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor

Comment: Just in case : Ubuntu stores root contab under `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`